# Как в Lua сделать / текстом

Tags: lua

```
currItemLabel = "Mobius "Unstable**/**Stable" Ingot"
```

Lua определяет символ **/** не как текст, как это можно исправить?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: `currItemLabel = "Mobius \"Unstable**/**Stable\" Ingot"`? `currItemLabel = [[Mobius "Unstable**/**Stable" Ingot]]`?

Comment: можно еще комбинировать одинарные кавычки и двойные, или экранировать кавычки внутри строки с помощью \" как в предыдущем комментарии.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш код, если Вы его правильно скопировали, должен вызвать синтаксическую ошибку.

Если Вы хотите использовать двойные кавычки в строковом литерале, заключите его в одинарные:

```lua
currItemLabel = 'Mobius "Unstable**/**Stable" Ingot'
```

или используйте многострочный синтаксис:

```lua
currItemLabel = [[Mobius "Unstable**/**Stable" Ingot]]
```

или экранируйте двойные кавычки:

```lua
local currItemLabel = "Mobius \"Unstable**/**Stable\" Ingot"
```